# Polymorphism in sysml

Tags: android-activity, polymorphism, sysml

currently i am trying to design an executable activity where a logical component send a request to several other logical components to start initialization. The usual way in activity diagram is to create for each block a swimline. But, as the number of LCs are high in this case the diagram will be extremely big and also later its modification will be a hurdle.

In programming, the solution to this problem is polymorphism where the objects are casted as the mother class and pushed into a vector and then within the loop the abstract function of the mother class is called.

I wonder if there is any similar solution to this problem in sysml or not?

I tried to assign one swimline to the all the LCs which recevie the request but it seems each swimline can only be assigned to a block.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a similar solution. Actually, it is even easier. Just let the ActivtyPartition represent a property with a multiplicity greater than 1. Any InvocationAction in this partition will then mean a concurrent invocation on all instances held in this property.

The UML specification says about this:

> **section 15.6.3.1 Activity Partitions**
>
> If the Property holds more than one value, the
> invocations are treated as if they were made concurrently on each
> value and the invocation does not complete until all the concurrent
> instances of it complete.

Typical InvocationActions are CallActions and SendSignalActions. So, you could call the `initialize()` operation in a partition representing the property `myLogicalComponents:LC[1..*]`.

If you don't already have defined such a property, you can derive it, by making it a derived union and then define all existing properties with components to be initialized as subsets of it:

```
/myLogicalComponents:LC[1..*]{union}
LC1:LC {subsets myLogicalComponents}
LC2:LC {subsets myLogicalComponents}
```

Of course, this assumes, that all your logical components are specializing `LC`, so that they all inherit and redefine the `initialize()` operation.

In SysML you also have AllocateActivityPartitions. No clear semantics is described for it, so I think you are better served with the UML ActivityPartitions, which are also included in SysML.

Comment: Hello Axel, thanks a lot for your reply. It seems that at least there is a solution, but i cannot realize it in Rhapsody. I wonder if you can give more hints how this solution can be realized for activity diagrams in Rhapsody?

Comment: My Rhapsody Version is expired, so I can't test it myself. You say, a swimlane can only represent a Block. If that is the case, Rhapsody is not following the standard. Any named element can be represented by a swimlane. So, it should be possible to let it represent `myLogicalComponents`. What does it even mean, when it represents a block? Which instance of the block is being adressed by this? Bear in mind, that there may be many instances, but only those in a certain subsystem should be initialized.

Comment: Another possiblity is to send an init-signal to a port and connect all components to this port. The signal will be forwared to all of them. Of course, another question is, whether a simulation will use this information. That really depends on the tool. Do you plan to simulate the activity?